# getting error in Switch(v.getId()) for image view

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, switch-statement, android-imageview

I'm trying to work on an exercise, which means i need to change an image from an imageView with a imageView as a Button ,when ever it is clicked. but i m getting an error on setting the switch case statement

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Switch;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
     ImageView display;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iVmg1);
    ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iVmg2);
    ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iVmg3);
    ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iVmg4);
    ImageView image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iVmg5);
    ImageView image6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iVmg6);
    ImageView image7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iVmg7);
    ImageView image8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iVmg8);
    ImageView image9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iVmg9);
    ImageView image10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iVmg10);



    image1.setOnClickListener(this);
    image2.setOnClickListener(this);
    image3.setOnClickListener(this);
    image4.setOnClickListener(this);
    image5.setOnClickListener(this);
    image6.setOnClickListener(this);
    image7.setOnClickListener(this);
    image8.setOnClickListener(this);
    image9.setOnClickListener(this);
    image10.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     Switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.iVmg1:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
                break;
            case R.id.iVmg2:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);
                break;
            case R.id.iVmg3:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.img3);
                break;
            case R.id.iVmg4:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.img4);
                break;
            case R.id.iVmg5:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.img5);
                break;
            case R.id.iVmg6:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.img6);
                break;
            case R.id.iVmg7:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.img7);
                break;
            case R.id.iVmg8:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.img8);
                break;
            case R.id.iVmg9:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.img9);
                break;
            case R.id.iVmg10:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.img10);
                break;


    }
}
}
```

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res     /android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.neelaysrivastava.wallpaper.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
android:background="#000000">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/img1" />
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/img1"
            android:id="@+id/iVmg1"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/img2"
            android:id="@+id/iVmg2"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/img3"
            android:id="@+id/iVmg3"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/img4"
            android:id="@+id/iVmg4"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/img5"
            android:id="@+id/iVmg5"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/img6"
            android:id="@+id/iVmg6"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/img7"
            android:id="@+id/iVmg7"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/img8"
            android:id="@+id/iVmg8"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/img9"
            android:id="@+id/iVmg9"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/img10"
            android:id="@+id/iVmg10"
            />
 </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Error:Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   Error:(67, 27) error: ';' expected
>   Error:(68, 17) error: orphaned case
>   F:\software\Wallpaper\app\src\main\java\com\example\neelaysrivastava\wallpaper\MainActivity.java

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: If its just a compile error - You have Switch instead of switch. Not sure if that's a typo or not

Comment: thx switch is the ans thx for the cooperation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
Switch(v.getId())
```

to

```
switch(v.getId())
```

This is just a compile error for [switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement.

And `orphaned case` Error means that you need include `default` section :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.iVmg1:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
                break;
            case R.id.iVmg2:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);
                break;
            case R.id.iVmg3:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.img3);
                break;
            case R.id.iVmg4:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.img4);
                break;
            case R.id.iVmg5:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.img5);
                break;
            case R.id.iVmg6:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.img6);
                break;
            case R.id.iVmg7:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.img7);
                break;
            case R.id.iVmg8:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.img8);
                break;
            case R.id.iVmg9:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.img9);
                break;
            case R.id.iVmg10:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.img10);
                break;
            // here
            default: 
                break;    
    }
}
```